# Is there a way to dynamically change or specify the location of an excel file in Workbook.Open?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote code to pull information from another workbook and copy it into my active workbook.

```vb
sub copydata
    
    Workbooks.Open "C:\User\abc.xlsx" 
    
    'test.xlsx is the active workbook, and abc.xlsx is the workbook data is being copied from
    Workbooks("abc.xlsx").Worsheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10"). Copy
    Workbooks("test.xlsx").Worsheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Workbooks("abc.xlsx").Close SaveChange:=True
    
End Sub
```

If this Excel sheet runs the macro on another computer the directory is going to be different and also the file name will have to remain the same.
**Is there a way to dynamically change this, or set this when the macro is launched via a button?**

Comment: It’s possible to change this, sure, but how do should the program know what new directory to find the file in?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it works this way but I didn't test it.

you can dim variables to take the place of the string you are using.

```
dim path as string
path = (wherever you are pulling the path string data from)
Workbooks(path).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Copy
```

you can actually do this for any of the parts in quotation marks. just dim the variable and populate it with a value
dim sheet as sheets
dim range1 as range
range1 = range("A1:A10")
sheet = worksheets("Sheet1")
should allow you to have all of the parts as variables. so the following code would work
Workbooks(path).Worksheets(sheet).range(range1).copy

Comment: also this code may help you with creating sub folders and accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

ThisWorkbook.path may be very useful to you. hopefully this makes sense what i'm doing because the code isn't complete enough to test from.

```
Dim Path1 as string
Dim Path2 as string
Dim Answer as boolean
Path1 = "Old"
Path2 = "New"
if Answer = true then
workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path &"\" & Path1 & "\Newfile.xlsm") 
else
workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path &"\" & Path2 & "\Newfile.xlsm")
end if
```

this example based on the value of "Answer" will save the file to one path or another.